# Posting tweet with URL, parsing for twitter via API (using tweepy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to post tweets using the [tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) (python api for twitter). I have a long url using the [itty bitty](https://itty.bitty.site/#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), to host a page of markdown. The Link can be posted via twitter website ([tweet here](https://twitter.com/I03Updates/status/1196781444976271360)), but not via the api. The error returned indicates the tweet is too long: 
`tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 186, 'message': 'Tweet needs to be a bit shorter.'}]`

I have ensured the tweet is below the character limit, minus the characters used by the URL limit for the [t.co shortening](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/url-shortener) (currently 23 per url). Unsure of what to try next?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you provide the code for what you're trying?

Answer (score 1):

Was an error in passing a list to the api.update_status(), this should only be passed strings, but error was not clear to pull this up.